# Select data from multiple databases dependent on row value

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, multiple-tables

I'm trying to select data across multiple databases.  I'm able to join the databases however, i'm not sure of how to dynamically declare which database to query data from.

e.g.

```
SELECT
    UID
   ,ACCT
   ,Comp 
FROM db1.dbo.tbl1
    JOIN db2.dbo.tbl1 
        ON db2.dbo.tbl1.uid=db1.dbo.tbl1.uid
```

The problem with this is it does not take into account which comp is defined in db1.  (comp = comp1, comp2, comp3).  Dependent on value of comp, query should provide results

(I'm sure the following is wrong)

```
SELECT
    uid
  ,acct
  ,comp 
FROM 
  (case when comp='comp1' 
        then db2.dbo.tbl1 
        when comp='comp2' 
        then db3.dbo.tbl1 
        when comp='comp3' 
        then db2.dbo.tbl1
   )

(Insert join clause)
(Insert where clause)
```

Comment: From what table is the value for comp coming from that you want to use to deteremine which table to join to?

Comment: @nscheaffer the value is coming from db1.dbo.tbl1.comp

Answer (score 0):

Consider a union query

```
SELECT UID, ACCT, Comp 
FROM db1.dbo.tbl1
JOIN db2.dbo.tbl1 
  ON db2.dbo.tbl1.uid = db1.dbo.tbl1.uid
WHERE comp IN ('comp1', 'comp3')

UNION

SELECT UID, ACCT, Comp 
FROM db1.dbo.tbl1
JOIN db3.dbo.tbl1 
  ON db3.dbo.tbl1.uid = db1.dbo.tbl1.uid
WHERE comp='comp2'
```

Comment: thanks!  This seems to done the trick.  Can the same unions be used when updating values to tables?